# Contour correct using \scalebox negative for reflection?

Tags: graphics

The `\scalebox` command can be used for reflection:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
D \scalebox{-1}[1]{D}\par
\end{document}
```

In the above, the second D is horizontally reflected. Good. I also could have used `\reflectbox{D}` for this particular effect.

My question: A glyph's outermost contour is supposed to be drawn clockwise; the inside hole is drawn counter-clockwise. But when the glyph is reflected, are the contour orientations also corrected? That is, does the reflected D have its outermost contour clockwise, or counter-clockwise?

Admittedly it looks fine in the PDF. Possible issue in commercial printing (not sure).

Comment: At a low-level, reflections, _etc._ are transformation matrix operations so the glyph is unchanged from just typing it in. I'm not sure if that answers the question: perhaps a trace of the box structure?

Comment: @JosephWright My minimal understanding of transformation matrix operations, leads me to believe that the contour orientation is uncorrected (outermost becomes counter-clockwise). Correcting it would involve (maybe) re-numbering the points. Maybe.

Comment: A simple letter isn't included in a PDF as a set of points, it's just a letter with the appropriate font selected. So there are no 'points' to move around ...

Comment: @JosephWright Ah. I hadn't thought of it that way. I supposed that the reflected glyph was "constructed from" the original glyph as a drawing object, rather than referring to it as a font character. In the latter case, should not be a problem.

Comment: @JosephWright You are correct. Please post as answer. How I verified: In an external PDF viewer, the reflected text (along with other text) could be selected, copied, then pasted as text into a text editor. That means that the reflected letter is still "a letter" not a drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detail of how `\scalebox` and similar are implemented depends on the driver in use, as these are not operations supported by TeX itself. However, the drivers have one key aspect in common: they don't attempt to  stroke the path of letters here, they apply a transformation matrix to the 'content' (whether it be letters, lines or anything else). For example, if we run the example in the question with `\showoutput` active and pdfLaTeX as the engine we get a box which contains

```
......\pdfsave
......\pdfsetmatrix{-1 0 0 1}
......\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x0.0, glue set - 7.6389fil
.......\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x7.6389
........\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 D
.......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
......\pdfrestore
```

*i.e* the graphic state is saved, a transformation matrix is applied and the content is inserted. (The `\pdfmatrix` primitive is equivalent to the PDF `cm` operation but with the two translation values automatically zero.) Other drives work in broadly the same way with the detail of the specials varying (see `dvips.def`, *etc.* for the current versions or the LaTeX3 driver set for commented implementations covering the same ideas).